# EntityManager not persisting properly

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring-boot application with hibernate and jpa. When trying to create new instance of `Foo` entity (by either `JpaRepository` or `entityManager` directly) everything seems fine (no errors, and returned instance's `id`s are incrementing), however these instances are niether saved into db nor returned when queried to orm (niether by `JpaRepository.findAll()` nor `entityManager.find(FooImpl.class, id)`)

I tried calling `saveAndFlush` method instead of `save` of `JpaRepository` -> Error thrown (no transaction)

I tried flushing `entityManager` manually -> same error.

I checked `entityManager`'s flushMode -> it was 'AUTO'

I tried querying for instances directly with `entityManager.find(CourseImpl.class, id)` -> no instance was found

I tried annotating service methods with `@Transactional` -> no difference

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class FooImpl implements Foo{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String someOtherValue;

    ...

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

My `Application.java`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public javax.sql.DataSource primaryDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("n0tRea1Pasw0rd");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc\\:mysql\\://localhost\\:3306/bar");
        dataSource.setSchema("bar");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorCustomAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.baeldung.persistence.model", "cz.mycompany.bar.domain"});

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        Application.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

relevant methods from service:

```
...
    @Override
    public Foo create(){
        return fooRepository.save(new FooImpl());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Foo> findAll() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(fooRepository.findAll());
    }
...
```

my `fooRepository`:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "foo", path = "foo")
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<FooImpl, Long> {}
```

for which i also tried custom implementation with:

```
public class FooRepositoryImpl implements FooRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
...
    @Override
    public <S extends FooImpl> S save(S entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
//        entityManager.flush(); this threw error
        return entity;
    }
...
}
```

Current state is a result of upgrading effort to Java 11, so i include relevant parts of `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        ...
        <java.version>11.0.2</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11.0.2</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11.0.2</maven.compiler.target>

        <jsoup.version>1.7.3</jsoup.version>
        ...
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!-- exclusion of tomcat because of jetty -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            <!--<version>${spring.version}</version>-->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>

        <!-- tomcat - default -->
        <profile>
            <id>tomcat</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        ...
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you try adding a `@Configuration` annotation to the class that has the `@ EnableTransactionManagement` annotation?

Comment: @Gimby  tried, i did not notice difference in behavior

Comment: Here is my line of thinking: if you expose beans in Spring Boot, it needs to be in a class annotated with `@Configuration`. The situation you describe to me sounds like the insert is not happening in the database you specify here, but to an in-memory database that Spring would setup when there is no datasource configuration at all. As in... when the beans in this class would not actually be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was wierd default transaction handling (JPA repositories wrapped their methods in `@Transactional`, so the it did not matter whether i did too or not). Issue was fixed by by creating "custom" transaction manager bean. Specifically `Application.java` was enriched by this:

```
...
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
...
```